# Why there are multiple window objects in heap snapshot

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, v8

I am learning about heap snapshot and while playing i came across one weird observation
as attached in screenshot I see there are **multiple window objects inside "Window" constructor with different @Id**.
I have did nothing just opened a new tab and just took a snapshot.

1. **From where these objects are coming ? How they are created ?**\
2. **Also what's difference between "Window" "Window /" constructor** [image]

Comment: How many enabled chrome extensions do you have? Is this number something about 29?

Comment: no, I have just 2 extentions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each active Chrome extension, each frame has its own context and a global window object. Click on any Window to see `native context` or `__proto__` or `global_proxy`. See examples:

[image: Window / stackoverflow.com]

[image: Window / chrome-extension:]

Just walk through Window objects and you will see the details w/o having to ask questions on SO. You also will be surprised by having more than 2 extensions.

Comment: I checked there are 2 window objects with different id having native context to stackovberflow.com, even i have only one tab of SF opened

Comment: I am using CEF to launch my site and I there are multiple window object formated with pointing native context to themself, ... why?

is this a bug with CEF ?

Comment: *even i have only one tab of SF opened* You missed iframe on SO.

Comment: how to identify which window object belong to which iframe, in case if there are 10's of iframe in my web page ?
\
There is one "Window /" where this object points to ? like is it of iframe !!

Comment: This's another question. It's better to ask a new one for make it possible to answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75315018/how-to-identify-which-window-object-is-related-to-which-iframe-in-heap-snapshot,
Done can you please help me to get it clarified

Answer (score 0):

1. why there are 2 window object pointing to stackoverflow
2. What "Window /" represents in highlighted text
   [image]