# How to identify which window object is related to which iFrame in Heap snapshot

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, v8

I am learning about heap snapshots, and when i took a snapshot of frame having 10's of iframe, i see multiple window object's in summery view.
**How can i identify which window object belongs to which iFrame ?**
What **Window ** object selected in picture represents ?
[image]

Comment: I don't see `Window /` in my Chrome. I guess I have disabled advertisements as it can be done by any highly rated SO user.  I thinks `Window /` is an untitled iframe from the left pane "Stack Overflow for Teams". I don't have time for taking deeper look at it right now.

Comment: I deleted all iframes and then took snapshot, still they exisits

Comment: I searched and removed all `<iframe` in Elements and one `Window /` disappeared. The tab itself is also web contents, so the last one `Window /` can be related to the tab window.

Comment: can you please also help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75320385/is-symbol-windowdocumentcachedaccessordetached-htmldocument-garbage-in-heap

Comment: can you also please help me in getting clarity for these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75332961/uses-of-summery-view-and-containment-view-in-heap-snapshot