# Is <symbol Window#DocumentCachedAccessor>::Detached HTMLDocument garbage in heap snapshot?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, v8

I was investigating my application's memory usage using heap snapShot.
I found there are some "Window objects" created having property "**<symbol Window#DocumentCachedAccessor>::Detached HTMLDocument@362261**".

1. Is this a garbage, if yes how to clear it?
2. What is meaning of **symbol V8PrivateProperty::CachedAccessor::kWindowProxy** [image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzGZ0.jpg)

Comment: It looks like a memory leak. 573 MB are too much. Look for leaks in your JS code.

Comment: I checked when i click on "Collect Garbage" most of these window object gets disappeared, 
Why GB didn't collect these win objects and i need to explicitly call "collect garbage" ?