# Uses of Summery view and Containment view in Heap snapshot

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chromium, v8, chromium-embedded, chromium-tabs

I was learning to on how to snapshot of javascript heap memory and I came across 2 terms
**"Summery View" and "Containment view"**.
The definition provided by there documentation is not clear and doesn't helps in understanding there usage
**Can any one please help me to get clarity on following questions please?**

1. When to use summary view and containment view, with a small example
2. In containment view the "retained" size of all element doesn't sum up to be total size of snapshot, then were i can find rest of memory being used
3. In summery view, total retained memory size looks greater then total heap size, why?